# Error when transforming my Python code to .EXE using Auto Py to Exe

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter, auto-py-to-exe

After converting my Python code to an executable, I am getting the following fatal errors when trying to run the program:

**1. Failed to run pyiboot01_bootstrap script**

**2. Error: "NoneType" object has no attribute "write"**

**3. Error described in the figure: pic3.jpg**
[Error 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHoHU.jpg)

Note: The program works perfectly when running on VS Code. The program is basically an interface that extracts data from a text file. I attached the program below and the screens with the code that generated my .exe file

[image: Screen Auto py to exe]

[image: Screen output Auto Py to exe]

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried "one dir" rather than "one file"? I sometimes find "one dir" to have better compatibility

Comment: yes, i tried unfortunately ...... but as suggested, i will try to run directly through Python

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with pyinstaller itself..

Reinstall pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe and try again..

Comment: the program works correctly when I run it directly from cmd -> python "Import_DBAR.py"

If you are interested, follow the link:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bf04juewmwlaqm2/AADU9aUmKwcI63j-KzeiueCGa?dl=0

Comment: after carefully looking at the error messages.. You must reinstall pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe